# MyAddress.class applet - set value (IP address) to form field

Tags: javascript

I'm testing MyAddress.class found here: http://www.reglos.de/myaddress/MyAddress.html and I'd like to add an IP address to a form.

The code alerts the user of their IP, which I don't need, but left it in to make sure the script was working. I'm close to filling the field in with the IP address, but I'm driving myself insane trying to find the answer. I don't know javascript.

```
<form name="form_2">
<input type="text" name="fieldname">
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
function MyAddress(IP) {alert(IP)} 
document.form_2.fieldname.value = AND I'M STUCK
</script>
<APPLET CODE="MyAddress.class" MAYSCRIPT WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0></APPLET>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to do:

```
function MyAddress(IP) {
    document.form_2.fieldname.value = IP;
}
```